# How do I detect an especific opacity of a gameObject? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know how to get a certainly value from the opacity of my gameobject. I wanna do a laser, so I did an animation of my laser going from 0 to 230, and then back to 0. I want it to make damage only if it's in 230 of opacity but I don't know how ;(. Can somebody help me? [this is a part of my animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B11O6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Color internally is stored as `float` values `0` to `1`.

So assuming you have access to your object it would probably be something like e.g.

```
public class DamageController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you drag in the according object
    [SerializeField] private Renderer renderer;

    // Due to imprecision I would go one lower just to be sure
    private float targetAlpha = 229f/255f;

    private void Update ()
    {
        if(renderer.material.color.a >= targetAlpha)
        {
            // However you deal damage
            DealDamage (amountPerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**However**, checking the alpha isn't actually necessary!

You have an animation anyway so you can also simply have the component reduced like

```
public class DamageController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update ()
    {
        // However you deal damage
        DealDamage (amountPerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

And now simply additionally **animate** the `enabled` state of this component!

Make it disabled by default and only enable it within the animation during the desired period.